# Error while loading shared libraries when running executable

Tags: c++, makefile

When I make the Makefile everything works fine, I get a library in the directory dir. And when I run "Make test" I get a testfile that I want to run. But when I want to run this file I get this weird error: ./programma: error while loading shared libraries: libprogramma.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I have tried running the program on both WSL and Linux, but nothing makes this error go away. Can anyone help me?

Here I have my Makefile which makes the library and the executable:

```
INC_DIR     = include
SRC_DIR     = src
SOURCES     = $(sort $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cc'))
OBJECTS     = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
DEPS        = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
TARGET      = programma
CXX         = g++
CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS    = $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIR))
.PHONY: all clean debug release
release: CFLAGS += -O3 -DNDEBUG
release: all
debug: CFLAGS += -O0 -DDEBUG -ggdb3
debug: all
all: $(TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS) lib/*.so programma *.d
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o lib/lib$@.so $^
-include $(DEPS)
%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC -MMD -o $@ -c $<
test:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -L./lib $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -o programma tests/main.cc -l$(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executables on Linux don't look for shared libraries in the directory they're located in, at least by default.

You can either fix that at link-time, by passing `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`, or at runtime, by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to the directory with the library. (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/lib ./programma`)

Comment: Can you maybe show me an example on how to fix it at link-time? With what I have to add to the makefile.

Comment: @Peredurz But I've told you the linker flag you need to add.

Comment: Oh, I have found what I need to do, thank you for your help